# Keycloak : Use service account with token that never expire

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, service-accounts, keycloak-rest-api

I'm using Keycloak and SpringBoot API.
My goal is to be able to use the keycloak Admin REST API with a token that is generated only one time.
I have enabled the service account, but the token expires after few seconds.
What can i do to generate a token that NEVER expire ? (like on Openshift service account)

If it not possible, how can i connect my springboot service to the Keycloak instance ?
Do i need to generate each time, before each request a token ??

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8081/auth/realms/api/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=admin-cli' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=f8111a95-67dd-412e-9e04-cf044f0e0286'
```

Thanks for any information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement a little helper component that provides the token centrally, refreshing it automatically behind the scenes (if necessary). The response from Keycloak includes an `expires_in` property which holds the token expiry in seconds, and the token itself carries expiry information in the standard `exp` claim.

Comment: Do you have an example of this implementation ?

Comment: I just created a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/slauth/19d0a558c386e4679c5b81625a4b2d00).

Comment: Thanks will check this

Answer (score 1):

Keycloak provides a Java-based admin client for this purpose. It handles authentication and token refresh for you.

The Maven coordinates are as follows:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
    <version>15.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Sources are available at Github at https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/integration/admin-client

The entrypoint will be the `Keycloak` class, Javadocs can be found [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.0/javadocs/).

Comment: you can use the KeycloakBuilder class  to build an instance of Keycloak, then use it: .getTokenManager() to retrieve a TokenManager, which have a  getAccessToken() method. This method always return a usable, non expired access token.